# svn copy returns "Repository moved permanetly"

Tags: svn

I've always used TortoiseSVN, but now I need to create a branch using the command line, and I cannot seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to follow the steps listed here [Branching Instructions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-sect-2.1)

And I'm using the following command

svn copy https://coolserver:8443/svn/Actant/trunk https://coolserver:8443/svn/Geneva/branches/NewBranch -m "Creating a private branch of trunk."

But I ever time I do, I get the error 
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://coolserver:8443/'; please relocate

Can anyone help me figure out what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually copying from one repository (Actant) to another (Geneva)?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I wasn't intentionally trying to copy from one repo to the other, it was a simple typo.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the repository location has moved from https://coolserver:8443/svn to https://coolserver:8443/. You can fix your working copy to reflect that, by [running](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)

```
svn switch --relocate https://coolserver:8443/svn/ https://coolserver:8443/
```

Or you can run your copy command directly on the repository like this:

```
svn copy https://coolserver:8443/Actant/trunk https://coolserver:8443/Geneva/branches/NewBranch -m "Creating a private branch of trunk."
```

Comment: The repository is definitely not moving. I can still use Tortoise like I always have. And the command you've given is the same as the one I'm running, only you're omitting the svn in the path, which may be accidental, but regardless, it doesn't work.

Comment: And again, Occum's Razor wins. I had a typo in the path. I checked the path for typos about 10 times, but never saw it until I got up, went to lunch, came back and checked one last time before committing Hare Kare.

Comment: Sorry about that. Couldn't see your typo from over here :-). But I'm glad you didn't have to commit hare kare...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a simple typo. Actant and Geneva are two different repos, so you can't copy from one to another. This is why you shouldn't try to code and talk to people at the same time.

The correct command, for anyone who happens to be interested would be

svn copy https://coolserver:8443/svn/Actant/trunk https://coolserver:8443/svn/**Actant**/branches/NewBranch -m "Creating a private branch of trunk."